# predefine what type of variable i'm making

Tags: javascript, variables, integer

I bet the following situation can be more efficient by removing the part from `jc.half = jc.half();`. I'm just not quite sure how.

```
jc.half = function(){

    if(jc.singlerow){
        return jc.total
    }else{
        return jc.total / 2;
    }

}
// returns function()

jc.half = jc.half();
// returns the right integer
```

I'm looking for a solution that does something like this:

```
jc.half = returnInteger(function(){

    if(jc.singlerow){
        return jc.total
    }else{
        return jc.total / 2;
    }

})
// returns the right integer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jc.half = (function() {
  return jc.singlerow ? jc.total : jc.total / 2;
})();
```

The trick is that when you've got a function declaration that *starts* in such a way that the parser can tell that it's meant to be a *value* in an expression, then the function definition *is* part of the expression, and you can use it that way and invoke the function. Really, on the right side of an assignment like that, it's not even necessary to use the "wrapper" parentheses, but I do it just out of habit and to keep things clear to myself when reading code.

Of course in *this* case you could omit the function entirely.

```
jc.half = jc.singlerow ? jc.total : jc.total / 2;
```

*edit* — a helpful commenter notes that you mention you need an integer; if so, you'll want to call `Math.floor()` or `Math.round()` on your result. Or you could "cheat" a little and do this:

```
jc.half = ~~(jc.singlerow ? jc.total : jc.total / 2);
```

Comment: need an integer response, add `Math.floor` around that division.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of getting the right type... you defined the function, but didn't execute it! You can make it self executing:

```
jc.half = (function(){

    if(jc.singlerow){
        return jc.total
    }else{
        return jc.total / 2;
    }

}) (); // Notice the empty brackets that actually execute the function
```

Although, is it even necessary to have the function?

```
jc.half = jc.singlerow ? jc.total : jc.total /2;
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear why you need a function.

```
js.half = js.singlerow ? js.total : Math.floor(js.total/2);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what i'm looking at here. Are all you guys giving me the solution in shorthand notation, or IS the solution shorthand notation? I can't figure it out since the notation is not familiar to me.

Comment: `?` is the ternary operator. Could be written like `if (js.singlerow) { js.half = js.total; } else { js.half = Math.floor(js.total/2); }`